# Wrong abstract header in memoir

Tags: header-footer, memoir, abstract

The header of the abstract of my thesis is the header of the previous section, Abbreviations, it should be "Abstract" instead of "Abbreviations", but I don't know how to fix it. Here is the latex code of my thesis:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_CA
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{saidphdthesis}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{title}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures*
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables*
\cleardoublepage

\include{nomenclature}

\include{abstract}

\include{acknowledgement}

\pagenumbering{arabic} 

\include{Introduction}

\include{chapter1}

\include{chapter2}

\include{chapter3}

\include{conclusion}

\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\bibliography{merged}
\end{document}
```

`saidphdthesis` is the style file that includes all the settings of the thesis.

Any help would be more than welcome.

Comment: What Peter said, plus we have no idea what's inside saidphdthesis. If we are going to help you'll need to post something that shows the problem, is minimal, and is selfcontained so others can copy and test as is. Here we have to guess and thus we cannot help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by including the following line at the end of `abstract.tex`:

```
\markboth{Abstract}{Abstract}
```

Comment: Erh, memoirs own abstract env does not write to the headers. If you had shown what was in the abstract file you might have gotten help faster

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is a mystery wrapped up in `\include{file}` where we have no idea what is in the various `file`s. Try debugging it yourself by replacing  each `\include{file}` by the first few lines of the `file` (no need to go beyond `{chapter2}`, also just keep the `\tableofcontents*` but not the other `listof...`.  Also replace the first `\pagenumbering{roman}` by `\frontmatter` and the first `\pagenumbering{arabic}` by `\mainmatter`. You would do well to  consider providing an MWE of the edited code.

Check the `memoir` documentation (`> texdoc memoir`) for the effects of `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`.